# Should we use <label> for every <input>?

Tags: css, xhtml, accessibility, screen-readers

Should we use `<label>` for every `input`? , even for submit button and keep hidden thorough css if we don't want to show `label`.

or no need of label for submit button?

```
.hide {display:none}

<fieldset>
  <legend>Search</legend>
    <label for="Search">Search...</label>
      <input value="" id="Search" name="Search">
    <label for="Submit" class="hide">Submit</label>
      <input type="submit" value="Go!" name="submit" id="submit">
</fieldset>
```

or we should use like this (no label for submit)

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Search</legend>
    <label for="Search">Search...</label>
      <input value="" id="Search" name="Search">
      <input type="submit" value="Go!" name="submit" >
</fieldset>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we put <input> inside <label>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895328/should-we-put-input-inside-label)

Comment: @Jitendra: You are asking similar QUESTION with little modification. Since you are a questioner here on SO, don't ask a similar QUESTIONS to save the database of SO :)

Comment: Yup, has asked 673 questions with only 96 answers although no one is restricted to that.

Comment: @Web Logic: Agreed there is no restriction he can ask as many as he want :)

Comment: @Sarfraz Ahmed - What you found duplicate? tell me? one is about to use `<label>` for every `input`, inside or outside doesn't matter and another one is about to put `input` inside or outside `label`. for me both are different question.

@Web Logic - it's not necessary to match number of answers with questions.

Comment: @Jitendra: you said "*for me both are different question.*" but for me it is not, it is **basically ** the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Don't use labels for elements which have intrinsic label text (e.g. all kinds of buttons). (Note: Faking a label with the `value` attribute doesn't count).

See the description section of the [WCAG section](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H44.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation:

> The LABEL element may be used to
> attach information to controls. Each
> LABEL element is associated with
> exactly one form control.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL

Note that the term is "**may be**," not "**must be**." However, it is always a good idea to use a `label` because this turns out to be handy for accessibility reasons and for browsers running on touchscreen devices.

Comment: Actually, this answers your question perfectly.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid if it doesn't answer your question, perhaps you could provide a little more information why not???

Comment: @Neurofluxation,  @Christian Payne - if there was any problem in given info in the question then how David Dorward gave very well and accurate answer.

Comment: @Sarfraz - you are right "it is always a good idea to use a `label`, this turns out to be handy" but not for every input. it's mentioned in a link provided in David Dorward's answer. my question not should we use `<label>` or not, my question "Should we use `<label>` for every `<input>`"

Comment: @Jitendra: i answered your question: "*Should we use <label> for every <input>*" with Note the term may be not must be. It shouldn't be used for every field. Thanks