# how can I replace the html syntax to razor syntax

Tags: html, razor, html-helper

I have a page in html format and I want to change that into the razor syntax. Here is the code:

```
<label class="class1" for="textinput">
    <button class="class2" href="#abc">Send</button>&nbsp;To
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Razor **HtmlHelpers**:

```
@Html.LableFor(model => model.textinput)
//or @Html.Lable("textinput")
<button class="class2" <--!href="#abc"-->>Send</button>&nbsp;To
//we don't have 'href' attribute in button tag
@html.ActionLink("Action", "Controller", null/*routing values*/)
```

do you wanna have a `Button` inside `Label`? To understand more [read this](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPnet/mvc_htmlhelpers.asp).

**Edit:**
[According to W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL), The label itself may be positioned before, after or around the associated control. See [Should I put input tag inside label tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-tag-inside-label-tag) and [Should we put  inside ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895328/should-we-put-input-inside-label) for more understanding. But, If you really wanna do that, You cant use `@Html.Label` or `@Html.LabelFor`, because of non potentiality of putting element inside it via Razor Syntax.

Comment: Hi Amir, I want button inside label only

Comment: @Divya I Updated Answer for you.